# Oauth2 login with Apple ID returns request without CSRF token

Tags: spring-boot, security, oauth-2.0, csrf-token, apple-id

I am trying to implement login with Apple ID in a Spring Boot application. I have it currently working so that I get the Apple login screen, and can authorize access. However, when Apple redirects back to `https://example.com/myapp/login/oauth2/apple`, I get the following error in my log :

```
2020-03-10 09:41:32.574 DEBUG 13644 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/oauth2/code/apple at position 3 of 16 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2020-03-10 09:41:32.574 DEBUG 13644 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login/oauth2/code/apple at position 4 of 16 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2020-03-10 09:41:32.575 DEBUG 13644 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for https://example.com/myapp/login/oauth2/code/apple
```

How can I make this work properly, without disabling CSRF facilities?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the same issue..

Comment: No, I haven't solved this. I've been in contact with Apple support and this did not lead to anything substantial either. Since due to circumstances the project it was part of got it's apple id login support cancelled I did not further pursue this. I am sorry I can't help you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the samesite=lax in 'session' cookie. Because of that, previous session related to login is being blocked by browser and new session is being created after Apple redirects to redirectUrl. This happens to all POST requests, since it is security issue and browsers drop cross-domain cookies. In order to resolve this issue, I disabled samesite in chrome and added the following config to my backend:

```
@Configuration
public class CookieConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public CookieSerializer cookieSerializer() {
    DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
    serializer.setSameSite("none");
    serializer.setUseSecureCookie(true);
    return serializer;
  }
}
```

And my csrf config is as following:

```
.csrf(c -> c
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                    .ignoringAntMatchers("/login/oauth2/code/apple")
)
```

At least, this gives me a chance to test my code. I will keep updating if I find how to resolve this in production.